# webpack-dev-server to return auto-generated for specific URL?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a single page app which connects to a back-end REST API on a different server.

On `index.html` app load, first thing it does is `GET /env.json` which contains the URL for the REST API server. Obviously, it is different in prod than in test than in dev.

Is there any way I can add middleware to the webpack-dev-server so that when it sees `GET /env.json` it serves up automatically generated json (based on env var or other)?

If there is an easier way, I am open to it. My assumption was that dev and test would start a backend server and then configure response to `GET /env.json`, while prod would have a different file added or dynamically generated.

Comment: Looks like you can configure routes via `setup` option: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/lib/Server.js#L255

Comment: @BobSponge (your handle is great): that is great. Put it as an answer?

Comment: @BobSponge yeah that works! I just tried it. Put it as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to webpack-dev-server [source code](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/lib/Server.js#L255) there is `setup` option which takes `app` (instance of express) variable as function argument. So, you can manipulate routes by specifying this option in your config:

```
devServer: {
    setup: function(app) {
        app.get('env.json', function(req, res) {
            // ...
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you Bob.