# Webpack Dev Server Config to Proxy to Node/Express Server

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm currently using the webpack-dev-server proxy config like so:

```
proxy: {
  "*": "http://locahost:1234"
},
```

To delegate any requests to my express server running on another tab.

However, even from reading the docs: https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html

And this blog post: http://nikolay.rocks/2016-01-13-connect-webpack-to-backend

I can't figure out how to eliminate webpack-dev-server from serving front-end assets, and to instead, delegate that to the back-end.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215469/webpack-dev-server-to-return-auto-generated-for-specific-url/36215848#36215848) to similar question.

Comment: @BobSponge if you could be a little more specific and provide an answer below, I'd be happy to upvote it! I'm not clear on how the routing/middleware connects to the proxy server.

Comment: Answer will depends on how you want to use `webpack-dev-server` while you proxying all requests. HMR will not work in that case. And if you not interested in HMR, you can simply use nginx ot other web server to serve assets.

Comment: @BobSponge all I would like is very plain and simple have the webpack-dev-server forward all of my requests to my node/express server. I don't mind not having HMR or nginx. Do I need to use nginx?

Comment: Simple solution is serve HMR updates with your existing [express server](https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware#installation--usage) and not use `webpack-dev-server`.